# How to use wrap_content with ternary operator

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android(or any kind of front-end development). I want to set the `layout_height` of a view `wrap_content` or a fixed number, depending on the value of a boolean variable.

I tried this but it did not work. (errors occurred during build)
`android:layout_height="@{vm.active ?` wrap_content`:`230dp`}"`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope that helps,

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams"/>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="package......" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@{!vm.active ? LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT : @dimen/spacing_60" />

</LinearLayout>
```